# Post image on facebook from iphone app getting error

Tags: ios, facebook, post, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to post image on facebook from my application. 
I'm adding some of the tester in Role section stil I'm getting error

```
    <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x173f0540> { URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos } { status code: 403, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store";
    "Content-Length" = 138;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 08 Apr 2016 12:25:46 GMT";
    Expires = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"insufficient_scope\" \"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions\"";
    "facebook-api-version" = "v2.5";
    "x-fb-debug" = "ykTtJJLBH6+kIMTBZgp57OHBP7jrU+DjUhjNMftg4D9uu5oAwOAMflCDqCBEPuxPz7BnRQosYAwgu+0MkP6/cg==";
    "x-fb-rev" = 2274481;
    "x-fb-trace-id" = "DLGq2+8glRI";
} }
```

Comment: `\"insufficient_scope\" \"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions\""` – that’s the important part.

Comment: I already set this permission  by code

Comment: That doesn’t mean that the user has actually granted it to your app. Log your access token and [debug it](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), or make a request for `/me/permissions`, to see what permissions your access token actually includes.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"] for checking is publish_actions are available for this user.
Also you should check this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices There is part about images in content in this article.